# Dynamic radiobuttons, how do i connect them do an event?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have picture repo, foreach picture i want a radiobutton in my wrappanel. I want to connect all of these radiobuttons to an event, so when one is checked, all the properties of the pictures shows up on screen.

Problem is for some reason i cannot access the events members of radiobutton when creating them.

I've tried google, couldnt find same problem

```
public void UpdatePictures(PictureRepo pictureRepo)
       {
           foreach (var picture in pictureRepo.RepoCollection)
           {



               WP_mainWrapPanel.Children.Add(new RadioButton
               {

                   Margin = new Thickness(2, 10, 2, 10),
                   Height = 100,
                   HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                   VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                   Content = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(picture.PictureLink, UriKind.Relative)) },
                   Name = picture.Name.ToString(),



           });


           }
       }
```

Radiobuttons have an event for if the button is checked, i cannot access it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void SetupRadioButton()
    {
        RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton
        {
            Text = "Your Properties Here",
        };
        radio1.CheckedChanged += Radio1_CheckedChanged;
    }

    private void Radio1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: I create radiobuttons based on how many pictures there are, i dont see how this helps?

Comment: @Michalodzien - You wanted to run an event when the radio button is ticked, right?

Comment: For each radio button you create, point the CheckedChanged event to the Radio1_CheckedChanged method as shown: 

radioX.CheckedChanged += Radio1_CheckedChanged;

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your button, and keep a reference to it.Then you can add the event handler.

```
var btn = new RadioButton
{
    Margin = new Thickness(2, 10, 2, 10),
    Height = 100,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    Content = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(picture.PictureLink, UriKind.Relative)) },
    Name = picture.Name.ToString(),
};
WP_mainWrapPanel.Children.Add(btn);
btn.Checked += btn_Checked;
```

The event definition looks something like this

```
private static void btn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```